# How to refresh ssas cube database/table for report

Tags: ssas, reporting-services

The problem:  My SSRS report based on my Cube is not getting the latest data from the table associated with the Cube.  How do I either a) tell the report to use the latest table data, or b) delete any report cache file that might be preventing a table data refresh?

Using SQLserver, SSRS, SSAS v2008 R2.  I've updated a table structure and its data using queries inside the sql management studio.  In the cube using this database/table I've processed and deployed (the cube + .dsv), all looks good.  From the report I've tried refreshing the datasource fields, which works, but the data itself is NOT refreshed, and I can't find any options to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the cube to get refreshed data into the cube (and your report).  Here's [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RUkhEvTyss) on how to do this.

Also you may want to review the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175634%28v=sql.105%29), paying particular attention to the different types of OLAP cube processing that are available, i.e. full, incremental, etc... as you'll probably only want to add new records, rather than erase and full re-populate the cube data on each process.

Comment: good tips, thanks.  I was doing "Full Processing" (the default) on both cube and db but that wasn't refreshing the db data (but it was updating for the new columns).  Now, after app and server restart (for unrelated reasons), and another default Process, all db content seems to be refreshed for my reports.

Comment: Regarding the "Process Options" in the Process Database dialog, the GUI was poorly designed since one must click on the "Process Full" text to see the dropdown options (good design should make options obvious when they are not trivial).  The dropdown contains the granular options I was looking for but could not find in the documentation or other menu options.